# How to organize the directory used for a distributable Python module?

Tags: python, module

I'm creating a Python module. My question is how can I organize the distribution such that it has a directory structure similar to most of the standard Python modules. Is there anything similar to MakeFile in Python which has `setup.py` file name?

Directory Structure:

```
pymodule_x-y.tar.gz/
                   + pymodule/
                             + __init__.py
                             + pymodule.py
                   + setup.cfg
                   + setup.py
                   + test/
                         + test_case.py
```

Comment: You might want to look into creating egg files: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several options, including distributing egg files, tarballs, etc. A great resource on distributing Python packages is [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (still under development, but good nonetheless).